# How to connect localhost:3306 of mysql container via app container- docker

Tags: docker, containers

In my application setting I am connecting to db with below settings

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gosallowMultiQueries=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Now I have two container App and mysql. I have linked both container

```
docker run --name app --link mysql:dbalias appimage
```

but I am getting Communications link failure error. I am not able to connect with mysql server

I used below command to run mysql container:

```
docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pointing to `localhost` which means the app is trying to connect to `localhost` of it's own container. NOT the localhost of your host.

If those 2 containers are deployed inside the same user defined bridge network you can can communicate using container names:

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/gosallowMultiQueries=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

if they aren't you can use the container IP of the mysql container but this can change when the container restarts/is recreated. The recommended approach is to create a user defined bridge network:

```
$ docker network create my-network
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
73df63463bb2        bridge              bridge              local
4cabe965c01d        host                host                local
c94ae182d8fa        my-network          bridge              local
93ec6f5bf028        none                null                local
```

and start your two containers inside the same network:

```
$ docker run --name mysql --network=my-network -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest
```

When both containers are started inside the same user defined network you can communicate using container name (you can test by `docker exec` inside one of the containers and try to ping the other one using the container name).

Comment: Awesome! your solution fixed my issue. thanks a lot. Just a question. is their any way by which I don't have to change jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306 to jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306 in my application.

Comment: When you turn off docker networking (by deploying your both applications on the default host network (--network=host). Then it will work too but using the host network is not recommended. It's an advantage of docker to dockerize networking too. Another option is using --add-host during docker run and specify something like: docker run --add-host 127.0.0.1:mysql. This will add an entree in your /etc/hosts of your container which will map 127.0.0.1 to mysql (so when you ping 127.0.0.1 you will ping the mysql container but I thinkt his can cause conflicts because its your localhost). You can test

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-entries-to-container-hosts-file---add-host

Comment: Sure. I will try all the options you have suggested. Thanks again :)