# Connecting to mysql running inside a docker container using localhost and a port number

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have situation where i have MySQL and tomcat running inside two separate containers , and i am deploying a war containing a hibernate.cfg.xml with following connection URL 
`<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/development_Blobs_001</property>`

i have docker-compose.yml which looks like this

```
services:

    database:
        build : database
        restart : always
        ports : 
           - "3306:3306"  #HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT
        environment :
            MYSQL_USER : root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD : password

    webapp:
        build : server
        ports : 
          - "8080:8080"
        links :
          - database
```

now the problem is **i am able to connect** to the database if i use following connection URL

`<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://database:3306/development_Blobs_001</property>`

but then this needs to be changed in all my hibernate.cfg.xml i want to avoid this modification as its a pain ... How can i solve this problem ?

I am using docker-compose which by default creates a network and runs the container in that network i can use container name to establish communication between the containers , but i need to avoid replacing localhost with container name in all my cfg.xml files ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect localhost:3306 of mysql container via app container- docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51513377/how-to-connect-localhost3306-of-mysql-container-via-app-container-docker)

Comment: The canonical way to connect two containers in the same network is using the container name defined in docker-compose YAML. You could also try using IPs. But localhost points to the container itself. Sincerely, it should not be a pain to replace "localhost" to "database" in your XML with an IDE.