# Spring boot jar docker deployment throwing Connection Exception with MySQL Container

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker

I just started exploring docker today and I've been trying to spin-up Spring Boot Web app backed by MySQL DB.

I pulled a MySQL container and ran it using:

```
docker run -t --name mysql-docker-container -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=**** -e MYSQL_DATABASE=spring_app_db -e MYSQL_USER=app_user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=**** -d mysql
```

My `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:3306/spring_app_db?autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10
spring.datasource.username=app_user
spring.datasource.password=test123

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

with this, when I run my spring boot in IDE it's able to connect and perform CRUD on db table.
However, when I try to deploy it on docker and link with MySQL container it throws Connection Refused error.
My Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
LABEL maintainer="baljinder@gmail.com"
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar bootmysql.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "bootmysql.jar"]
```

The command I'm using to run docker image of the boot:

```
docker run -t --name spring-jpa-container -p 8080:8080 --link mysql-docker-container:mysql spring-jpa-app
```

Can someone please help with this. I've tried deploying both on the same container network by creating a docker network (`docker network create -d bridge sql_spring_network`) but the error persists.

Comment: Shouldn't you use another ip for the database connection, such as **localhost** or **127.0.0.1**?

Comment: Error persists when I use localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: Network port forwarding (-p <hostmachine>:<container>) should be enough to deal with this ideally but I went ahead and created a bridge network. Still error doesn't go away. I thought of setting up Docker Compose but I've read posts from people encountering similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

When using the [legacy](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) linking of containers using the `--link` flag. The "linked" container is available as a host in the running container with it's container name. So in your case, the mysql container is available in your app container with hostname `mysql`.

Your database url, therefore should be: `jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/spring_app_db?autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10`

Comment: Thank you so much. As a beginner I wasn't aware many of these tutorials available today are out of date and aren't considered best practices. If anyone else is stuck with same problem please go and read more about docker networks here <https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-connection-refused/> and people looking for a quick solution can jump to another answer from here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51513377/how-to-connect-localhost3306-of-mysql-container-via-app-container-docker>

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
jdbc:mysql://mysql-docker-container:3306/spring_app_db?autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10
```

replace:

```
jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:3306/spring_app_db?autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10
```